# Scala template accessing model object properties in Play 2.0

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple question regarding accessing member variables of a model object.

I have the following model objects:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model{
    @Id 
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Account extends Model{
    @Id
    public String email;
    public String password;
    @OneToOne
    public Person person;
}
```

So far so good, Any given `person` can have a single `account`. The `Account` object is copied from the zentask example. After authentication I redirect to the index page which displays the user realname as stated in the `Person.name` member variable. The `Account` object is inserted in the page just as with the zentasks example like so:

```
Account.find.byId(Controller.request().username());
```

Now the following strange things happen in the template which i do not understand:

```
@account.person.name
```

results in a `Null` value inserted in the template while calling:

```
@account.person.getName()  or   @account.person.getName
```

results as expected with the correct name inserted from the person object.

```
@account.person
```

shows the `.toString()` of the person object, also correctly showing the name.

So to summarize: What is wrong with the code above? Why can I call the account.person value without any problems, but when I call account.person.name this does not work anymore

Thank you in advance!

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because JPA uses Aspects to intercept getter usage and fill-in the missing data from objects that are lazy-loaded.  I don't know what conventional thinking is, but I would not use public members ever with JPA for this reason, it will break the framework consistently.

If you really want to use public members, you'll have to mark relationships as eager fetching:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

or explicitly fetch all of the object tree you'll need in your template (ugh).

In your case, the relationship, a OneToOne is defined on the other side of the relationship, if you define it on the Account side, it should fetch eager by default.  I forget if you can define OneToOne on both entities, I think you can, but you might have to fiddle with it a bit.

Overall, don't use public members with JPA, it will break.  Better yet, ditch JPA and use Anorm instead, it maps to the problem domain much more successfully than JPA.  Issues like this consistently cause JPA implementations to take up twice as much implementation time as anyone seems able to predict.

Comment: Hi PlexQ! Thanks for the response!
This behavior is quite strange, as with Play! framework you are encouraged to use public members in a class. I see how JPA (and in my case Ebean, which is default in Play!2.0) uses Aspects to perform lazy load. But one might expect this to work as mentioned above. Again thanks! I'm awarding you the points, as it seems I won't be getting a full answer from the community about this.

Comment: Another thought comes to mind: I wonder if using static weaving would improve this rather than load time weaving?  I could have sworn I remember it being possible to point cut field access, just JPA implementations I've used dont seem to. Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: The EBean implementation distributed as default ORM provider with the Play! 2.0 framework. I didn't hear of it until Play! came with it.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon an answer posted by Guillaume Bort, which explains things.
Read here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/CNjH3w_yF6E/discussion

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because of lazy loading the values in the field only get loaded when you access them from the class itself.(something that, in normal circumstances would use a setter/getter

In order to load the values you ether have to write getters and setters.
Or you can create a methode that checks every value.

you can add the following methode to your Account Entity:

```
public void checker(){

    if(email==null){}
    if(password==null){}
    if(person==null){}
}
```

this will load every value, but won't reduce performance